# strange behaviour with C++ bool data-type

Tags: c++

This is a curiosity question. I was working with a Boolean to keep track of some parts of my code. I had the Boolean, say `track` initialised to be `false`. Now when I change it somewhere else to true using integer constant like :

```
track = 1;
```

this is defined. I understand how this would work true being `1` and false being `0`. But now when you I say

```
track = 500;
```

this is still defined. Reasonable since it's any value other than or greater than `0` meaning it's true. My confusion now is when I do

```
track = 2147483648
```

which is 1 greater than `INT_MAX` the behaviour is still defined as true. Even when I push it a bit further to `2147483649454788`. But when I equate to `21474836494547845784578` it throws an error

> ```
> error: integer constant is too large for its type [-Werror]
>                      _softExit = 21474836494547845784578;
>                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Now this is just confusing. I'm pretty new to C++ so I'm not sure why or what any of this means. I know I could just use `track = true;` but I'm just curious.

Comment: It seems to mean that: "integer constant is too large for its type", ie. 2147483648 is too large to fit into an integer.

Comment: If it's too large to be an `int` literal, it'll be some other literal, possibly a `long long` literal. And then at some point it's too big to be any kind of integer literal, so you get the error.

Comment: Representing the number 21474836494547845784578 requires 75 binary digits.

Comment: Can you try with 9223372036854775807 and 9223372036854775808?

Comment: @Anže well `9223372036854775807` works just fine but `9223372036854775808` didn't.

Comment: @Blaze That makes perfect sense

Comment: One is maximum 64 bit signed int and the second is larger by one. ;)

Comment: This error message has exactly zero things to do with `bool`.

Comment: @n.m. I figured that out. I just didn't think about it carefully initially

Comment: It would be fun to try compiling it for 32 bit architecture. If I am correct then it should stop at max signed 32 bit int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have discovered yourself, an `int` object implicitly converts to a `bool`. So does a `long long` (or `std::int64_t`). So far so good, but the compiler message you show has nothing to do with `bool`. It's just that what it says: in your program, you have an integer literal that doesn't fit into into the domain that built-in integer types can handle. Hence the error, you would get it without trying to initialize a `bool`.

So this is ok:

```
const bool test = std::numeric_limits<long long>::max();
```

while inserting the actual literal value that `std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()` yields `+1` is not ok.

Comment: Because it's not `INT_MAX` that makes the compiler refuse the conversion but the max value a 64bit integral value can be on your machine. I'll edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: It may be worth adding `test` will be `true`, which converts back to `1`, so `static_cast<int>(static_cast<bool>(42))` is `1`. That's usually the next thing that surprises people dicovering bool/int conversions.

Comment: @spectras Yes that I did and realised it does change everything to 1. pretty cool